# How to custom wrapfigure environment in preamble?

Tags: wrapfigure

I would use the following code many times in my latex note.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{10ex}
\vspace{-2ex}
\includegraphics[width=10ex]{any_picture.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

However it will be clumsy if I change one parameter(for example, change `{10ex}` to `{5ex}`) for all the pictures. How to custom `wrapfigure` environment in preamble so that I can easily
change the parameters of all pictures? The following is my code, please help me, thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titletoc} 
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{10ex}
\vspace{-2ex}
\includegraphics[width=10ex]{my_picture.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{10ex}
\vspace{-2ex}
\includegraphics[width=10ex]{my_picture.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{10ex}
\vspace{-2ex}
\includegraphics[width=10ex]{my_picture.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is why you have macros.

```
\newlength{\mywidth}
\setlength{\mywidth}{10ex}
\newcommand{\mypos}{r}
\newcommand{\mylines}{5}
```

Change parameters in the last three lines and in your code use them like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\setlength{\mywidth}{10ex}   %% <---- change here
\newcommand{\mypos}{r}       %% <---- change here
\newcommand{\mylines}{5}     %% <---- change here

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[\mylines]{\mypos}{\mywidth}
\vspace{-2ex}
\includegraphics[width=\mywidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{wrapfigure}[\mylines]{\mypos}{\mywidth}
\vspace{-2ex}
\includegraphics[width=\mywidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{wrapfigure}[\mylines]{\mypos}{\mywidth}
\vspace{-2ex}
\includegraphics[width=\mywidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a link for defining the new function http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129345/predefined-settings-in-wrapfig   But it's fault when compiling my picture.  However how to write the function(or the format of \newcommand) like in the link? Please supply the link of material about \newcommand. I want to learn more about \newcommand and macros. Thank you very much

Comment: @Hyden Instead of saying its faulty, can you please add that cpde to the question?. BTW you have to have more text in your paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the code that Harish Kumar posted. There is my another suitable answer following.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcommand{\testwrap}[1]
{\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{10ex}
\vspace{-2ex}
\includegraphics[width=10ex]{#1}
\end{wrapfigure}}


\begin{document}
\testwrap{example.jpg}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\testwrap{example.jpg}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\testwrap{example.jpg}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

I just define the `\testwrap` as the set of (macro)instruction. That's the macros that Harish Kumar mentioned. Thanks Harish Kumar.